# "Flashbacky" transition in Hitfilm

Tags: transitions, flash

I have a small movie I'm making that is just a bunch of discussions and flashbacks to the past, I wanted to find an appropriate transition, that's like a flash transition. I saw a few ways to do that but they're hard to recreate all over again. Please, give me ideas for a transition like that that is easy to replicate, because i need to use it very often. Thanks!

Comment: The question is clear, but I'm missing a lot of context information. What do you mean with "Hitfilm"? What video editor do you use? You are probably using the wrong tool if a flash transition is too much work. Are you sure your concept has a chance to work? I mean if a short movie has so many flashback that transitions are too much work, it probably means you have planned way too many flashbacks.  How many flashbacks are there approximately? Maybe your telling your story wrong: think of your audience - don't you think that many flashbacks will confuse them? What kind of movie is that anyway?

Comment: @Matt, [Hitfilm Express](https://fxhome.com/hitfilm-express) is a semi-popular NLE that, I think, predates Resolve being available for free. But, I agree, a flashback transition is probably a trope to be avoided.

Comment: I use Hitfilm Express, it's very similar to Premiere. And I can't really avoid the flashback, that's the whole point tand that's why asked the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know that editor. Well,it's your movie, your decision. I am sceptical but in no position to criticize your decision without seeing the result. It's just that I have my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple one you can do is a transition that is dipping to white. If your editor doesn't offer this kind of transition you can do the following: add a still image which is all white, do a cross dissolve from scene A to the white still, then a cross dissolve from the white still to scene B. Ideally the first time you use it is when audience can infer clearly from context that scene B is a flashback, so that they recognize that this type of transition represents a flashback. Also you may add a subtle, short sound effect.

It does not look that fancy, but should be easy to do and many would argue anyway to keep your transitions clean and simple anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! I oped for something similar, but with a circular iris instead of a cross dissolve.